# コマンドプロンプトでPythonのコードを実行するには？

Tags: python

最近Pythonの勉強を始めた学生です！
いくら調べても分からないことがあり、是非プロフェッショナルの皆様にお力を貸していただければと思い、投稿します。

コマンドプロンプトでPythonのコードを実行しようとしても、「'Python' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。」というメッセージが出てしまいます。

どのようにすればコマンドプロンプトでPythonのコードが実行できるのか教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: あなたが使っている OS は Linux でしょうか Windows でしょうか、それとも他の何かでしょうか。その辺を元質問の編集で追記していただくと回答が付きやすくなります。（コマンドプロンプトっすね）

Comment: @Yuki さん、Pythonをどのようにインストールしたのかを追記していただけるとばっちりな回答が書けるかもしれません。Pythonに限らず、あるソフトウェアを使えるようにする手段は通常複数あるため、「○○というやり方で使えるようになるはずだったのに、実際には××という風になる」というように書いて頂けると回答を書きやすいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowsの場合は環境変数`PATH`にPythonをインストールしたフォルダが設定されていないからです。
Windows10でPythonがPATHに設定されていない環境のコマンドプロンプトで`Python`と入力すると、Microsoft StoreのPython紹介/取得画面が出るので違うのかもしれませんが。

インストーラーのオプションにチェックボックスがありますから、初心者だというならそれを指定してインストールしておけばよいのでは？
[3. Windows で Python を使う](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/using/windows.html)
「Add Python x.x to PATH」の部分ですね。x.xにはPythonの版数が入ります。

自分で設定したい場合は、こちらを参考に。
[環境変数PATHを設定する](https://www.javadrive.jp/python/install/index3.html)

それと、Anaconda/Minicondaでインストールしたなら、スタートメニューからAnaconda PromptかAnaconda PowerShell Promptを起動すれば使えるコマンドプロンプトになるでしょう。

また、インストール時にオプションを変えていないなら、ランチャーがインストールされているので、`Py`と入力すればPythonが起動します。
[WindowsユーザーはPythonランチャーの存在を意識しましょう](https://gammasoft.jp/blog/find-out-python-launcher/)

他に、拡張子`.py`のファイルを`Python`のパラメータとしてではなく単独でそのまま実行したい場合は、拡張子の関連付けの設定が必要です。
この辺の記事を参考に。
[Python .pyファイルの関連付けが上手くいかなくて悩んだ件](https://qiita.com/no-use-kuro/items/cebfa03d73ff96195971)
[【ノンプログラマー向けPython】Anacondaでpyファイルをダブルクリックで実行できるように設定する](https://tonari-it.com/python-file-double-click-run/)